# How to remove audio track from a video file using Xuggler?

Tags: video-processing, flv, xuggler, xuggle

As part of processing the videos, I want to REMOVE the video information from the FLV video file. Idea is just to present the AUDIO to the user without showing any visuals. However note that I want to present this to the user as a video only so that it plays in the flash plugin in the browser, and user would just listen the audio.

I saw many posts which extracts the media, and I presume they just extract, and not REMOVE.

How xuggler can be used for this purpose? Any example code will be useful here.

/anil.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I'd also like to know

Comment: Yes, implement your class as follows.
public class <your class> extends MediaToolAdapter implements Runnable {
   ...
}

You can control encoding of the visual information in this method. 

public void onVideoPicture(IVideoPictureEvent event) { ... }